# After editing css in Chrome Developer Tools, css file does not load

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I'm developing a basic web page with css file on my local machine and testing by opening the html file in the browser straight from the filesystem.

This works, but now since using the Chrome developer tools to play around with different styles by editing the css file under the Sources tab, whenever I refresh the page none of the CSS loads until I again edit it in the sources tab - just adding a return to the end is enough to load all the CSS.

Also, occasionally when refreshing the page, the Sources tab shows the contents of the css file as corrupt (a load of random characters)

I've run the css through a validator and that says it is all fine and there is no javascript on the page

I'm not a web developer so probably missing something obvious...

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are editing `css` inside the Inspect Element (Chrome developer tools).

This is because the `css` literally lives on a webpage and it is pulled from your actual `css` file on your desktop (css file from the folder of your website).

Because of this, you are never actually changing an actual `css` on your computer, just in the browser, and that is temporary, because the same old css from your computer will load everytime you reload the page (untill you modify the css on your computer).

You should edit your changes in your actual `css` file on your computer inside your text editor (notepad++, visual studio code, atom, sublime text, etc ...).

That way, it is going to work as you want ! Hope you understood what I meant, if not, just tell me, so I can clarify again :)

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I do get that, the problem is when I reload the page it doesn't load the css file from disk - it only loads the css when I go back into the developer tools and edit it there

Comment: Are you opening your website by simply clicking on index.html file in your project folder, or are you using a text editor ?

Comment: Just double clicking the file in explorer (I'm on Windows) and opening in Chrome.  I'm editing inside a text editor but not launching the browser from there

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the nginx configuration:

```
http { 
    
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    ....
}
```

this solved it for me.

Thanks