# CSS styles not loading in to the page

Tags: php, css, amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I have a php website, it works well locally, and it has worked well via EC2 instances in AWS.

I have moved everything to Kubernetes now and got it all working except one of the stylesheets just isnt loading.

Its in the dev toolbar as loaded, and you can click on it and open it and see the styles, however they are not reflected at all.

If I go to the sources tab in the dev toolbar and go to the stylesheet, open it and literally just add a space, all of a sudden it all loads in. On refresh gone again.

Again, this doesn't happen locally via docker containers only when its running in EKS.

Similar question: [After editing css in Chrome Developer Tools, css file does not load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65329087/after-editing-css-in-chrome-developer-tools-css-file-does-not-load/)

Comment: Sounds like you might have a corrupted character at the start of you file.

Comment: why would it work on my local machine, and also work as soon as i put anything in to the css via the sources panel? bear in mind.. ive not changed this css since it was last fully working on an ec2 instance. the only diff is that its running in kubernetes now.

Answer (score 1):

Ive just found the answer, add:

```
http { 
    
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    ....
}
```

to the nginx config.